# I am unable to install on json on python 3.7 (The error below is what I am facing)

Tags: python

Error when trying to load data with module JSON

```
File "C:\Users\Harry Walia\Desktop\Python\json1.py", line 3, in <module>
    import json
  File "C:\Users\Harry Walia\Desktop\Python\json.py", line 13, in <module>
    json_obj = json.loads(data)
  AttributeError: partially initialized module 'json' has no attribute 'loads' (most likely due to a 
   circular import)
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Comment: You named your file `json.py` now it clashes with the built-in `json` library.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for this error is that you have a file in your current working directory named "json.py". Python already has the JSON module installed, so just make sure you haven't named any of your files "json.py"

Answer (score 0):

Python already has a built-in Json module, so you do not need to install it. Just head into your shell and type:

```
import json
```

And you'll have the JSON module!